# cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic IEnumerable to models in group by linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Im getting an error in my C# project which is causing me a headache. The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collecitons.Generic.IEnumbrable<Models.tbl_station>'
to Models.tbl_station An explicit conversion exists(are u missing a cast)
```

Here is my code.

```
var results =
    (from p in db.tbl_pageDetail                        
     group p by new { p.station_id, p.category_id } into g
     let pageno  = (from i in g select i.pageNo) 
     let station = (from i in g select i.tbl_station)
     select new 
     {
         g.Key.category_id,
         g.Key.station_id,
         pageno,
         station
     }).ToList();

var data =
    results.Select(x =>
        new tbl_pageDetail
        {
            category_id = x.category_id,
            pageNo = string.Join(", ", x.pageno),
            station_id = x.station_id,
            tbl_station = x.station // Here i getting error
        });

return View(data);
```

Comment: The error means `x.station` is a collection and `tbl_station` is not. Either change `tbl_pageDetail.tbl_station` to a collection or filter the `x.station` with a linq extension method like [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482.aspx).

Comment: What exactly is your requirement here? Each `result` in `results` collection will have `station` which in turn will be collection of `tbl_station` (line 5 query 1). You are later assigning this collection again to `tbl_Station` in second query. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is self explanatory! `x.station` is an `IEnumerable` and you are trying to store that in `tbl_station`. Just consider your own example:-

`pageNo = string.Join(", ", x.pageno)`

Here since x.pageno was an IEnumerable you were able to pass it to `Join` method to create a single item, Same is the case with `tbl_station = x.station`, here you have a List so you cannot store that into a single object, you either need an IEnumerable of tbl_station or you need to fetch a single item from x.station by using `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()`.